# Get multiple value with pattern in a column of Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a set of thousand data in sheet1 and

I hope to get some of the data with the following pattern into sheet2

(Pattern: three cells of every two rows like (A2,A4,A6) then
  (A102,A104,A106), (A202,A204,206) and so on.)

```
A2
A4
A6

A102
A104
A106


A202
A204
A206
```

I am new to Excel and I am very confused with it. 
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
=INDIRECT("sheet1!A"&QUOTIENT(ROW(A1)-1,3)*100+(MOD(ROW(A1)-1,3)+1)*2)